Can I hang a heavier pocket door on the original track?
I have an existing pocket door that leads from hall to laundry room.  I want to change just the door.  It's a crappy lightweight hollow door and I want to put in another door that I have sitting around - a French door with glass panes -- it's probably quite a bit heavier than the original.  Is a heavier door likely to destroy the track?  And if I do destroy it, how hard is it to replace that part without deconstructing the whole pocket system/wall?  I did consider searching for a lightweight door with windows - like for a mobile home.  But I already have a door I like that isn't being used.

Of course we can't know for sure from that vague description, but most pocket door hardware I've installed hasn't seemed to have a practical weight limit. We often used solid-core six-panel oak doors in our homes and it handled the weight without issue.
Screw some bags of sand to your door and see how it feels. If things aren't flexing, sagging, or dragging, all good. As RMDman suggests, check the track suspension screws and replace them if they don't at least reach the framing. Just don't crank them down so hard that you displace it.

Well, there’s some pretty weak pocket door hardware out in the wild, so it’s a non-zero chance of failure. Testing is a good idea. A picture of the existing track and roller would be a really good idea.

the door track and hardware does have a weight rating.  Finding that information will be the issue.  The best thing to do is replace the screws holding the track in with longer screws so the track is less likely to pull out of the wood.

@RMDman  That will also help to identify if enough screws were used initially, to be adequate for the heavier door - as you are hinting, the track may be adequate, but the mounting of that track also has to be adequate / correct etc.

Any weight rating on such hardware is probably so optimistic as to be useless. I'd trust empirical evidence over that. Replacing the screws is a good idea.
